# Django 2.0 Tutorial - Cant Acess Django-Admin Shell

Tags: python, django

When I attempt to acess the Django Shell using `Django-Admin Shell`, I get the error message:

```
 django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
(env2) Coreys-MacBook-Pro:mysite3 coreydickinson$
```

I've attempted the settings.configure() in the python shell, and I'ved tried redirecting the Django settings using `django-admin.py shell --settings=mysite.settings`. Neither worked. Anyone have any idea what I am doing wrong?

Full error:

```
(env2) Coreys-MacBook-Pro:mysite3 coreydickinson$ django-admin shell
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env2/bin/django-admin", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(execute_from_command_line())
  File "/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 371, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 365, in execute
    self.fetch_command(subcommand).run_from_argv(self.argv)
  File "/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 288, in run_from_argv
    self.execute(*args, **cmd_options)
  File "/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 327, in execute
    saved_locale = translation.get_language()
  File "/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 187, in get_language
    return _trans.get_language()
  File "/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/translation/__init__.py", line 55, in __getattr__
    if settings.USE_I18N:
  File "/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/Users/coreydickinson/mysite/DJDev/env2/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    % (desc, ENVIRONMENT_VARIABLE))
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: Requested setting USE_I18N, but settings are not configured. You must either define the environment variable DJANGO_SETTINGS_MODULE or call settings.configure() before accessing settings.
(env2) Coreys-MacBook-Pro:mysite3 coreydickinson$
```

Comment: Your settings.py have `USE_I18N` registered? 
Take a look in here:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#use-i18n

Comment: Try `python manage.py shell` from the same directory as your `manage.py` resides.

Answer (score -1):

You are supposed to use manage.py, not django-admin.py.